# Magetn2: How to install extension via composer with github and marketplace component

Tags: magento2

I need to install the extension via the composer without GitHub and marketplace component.

Need to install with local repo directory.

I am stuck with this. Can you please help with the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve.
But: Adding a composer dependency to your project without a (remote) repository for that dependency doesn't make sense.

If you want to require a local repository you can still do this, like this:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository
Just use a file path instead of http:

If you just want to install an extension from local files or zip just copy the extension files into the app/code directory of your Magento project like this: `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>`

Comment: If I have not added the files on Github repository then how i can install via composer (with extension zip file) with local file path?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Can you please please share steps with real zip example??

Comment: I have checked but no luck

Comment: Can you please share the steps?